# R "difftime" exhibits strange behavior

Tags: r, difftime

I am a bit confused by the function "difftime". When I calculate the time difference up to 27 March 2016 everything is ok. But as soon as I try 28, 29, 30 or 31 March 2016 there seems to be a problem:

```
> difftime("2016-03-27","1979-01-01", units="days")
Time difference of 13600 days
> difftime("2016-03-28","1979-01-01", units="days")
Time difference of 13600.96 days
> difftime("2016-03-31","1979-01-01", units="days")
Time difference of 13603.96 days
```

I can get around this problem by setting the date to 27 March 2016 and then adding manually the number of days "missing", but I was wondering if there is maybe something wrong with the function...? I don't really see what I could have done wrong since I just changed the day number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem, when you convert it with `as.Date`:

```
difftime(as.Date("2016-03-28"), as.Date("1979-01-01"), units="days")

# Time difference of 13601 days
```

Also there is no problem with `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)   
difftime(ymd("2016-03-28"), ymd("1979-01-01"), units="days")

# Time difference of 13601 days
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason an extra day in going from `2016-03-27` to `2016-03-28` is `0.96` is due to daylight savings time kicking in:

```
0.96 = 23 hours / 24 hours
```

Read [this R Nabble blog](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/difftime-result-for-days-not-an-integer-td1477769.html) which discusses this problem in detail.